# Функция the_field(); не работает на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил плагин Advanced Custom Fields. на Главной странице не могу вывести содержимое поля с помощью `the_field();`

Самое интересное на странице О нас всё работает.

В настройках чтения выбрано отоборазить статическую странице Главная.

```
<div class="sertificat">
    <a href="<? the_field('sertificate_1');?>"><img src="<? the_field('sertificate_1');?>" alt=""></a>
    <a href="<? the_field('sertificate_2');?>"><img src="<? the_field('sertificate_2');?>" alt=""></a>
    <a href="<? the_field('sertificate_3');?>"><img src="<? the_field('sertificate_3');?>" alt=""></a>
    <a href="<? the_field('sertificate_4');?>"><img src="<? the_field('sertificate_4');?>" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Comment: На главной странице - свои поля 'certificate_x', на странице О нас - свои.

Comment: И да, the_field() работает только в главном цикле WordPress. Где у вас этот код?

Comment: На странице о нас другие поля 'group_photo_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо вы не задали эти поля на главной странице (а они для каждой страницы свои), либо вы используете `the_field()` вне главного цикла WordPress. Во втором случае, вам надо указать вторым аргументом id поста, для которого вы хотите вывести эти поля.

```
the_field( 'sertificate_1', $post_id );
```

Comment: Поля задал, а как узнать $post_id?

Comment: Вначале все работало в процессе сломалось. посмотрите я фото файлов загрузил на вопрос

Comment: Да перечень файлов не нужен. Нужен код главной, чтобы понять, где у вас этот вывод. ID главной можно узнать в админке, при редактировании. url выглядит примерно так: `/wp-admin/post.php?post=1086&action=edit`. Вот это 1086 и есть id страницы

Comment: вариант с id сработал, класс. спасибо. интересно конечно же почему так

Comment: Я сказал, почему, прямо в ответе. Вы используете эту функцию вне главного цикла WordPress

Comment: Как тогда в таком случае "впихнуть" функцию в главный цикл WordPress?